# how to add close button on the top-center of BottomSheetDialog android?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, bottom-sheet

want to add close button on BottomSheetDialog to close it.

I'm using with custom view(Linearlayout) for BottomSheetDialog.

`filterDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(context);
filterDialog.setContentView(rootView);
filterDialog.getWindow().setWindowAnimations(R.style.CustomDialogAnimation);
filterDialog.show();`

below image is my filterDialog:

[image]

And this is what I want to achieve:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can do something similar by using an anchor https://medium.com/android-bits/android-anchoring-views-to-bottom-sheet-9c9069caf7d4

Comment: thank you but I just want to show close button when my dialog appeared.

Comment: Can you please share the `LinearLayout` which is used for your `BottomSheet`?

Comment: @NaseerAttari yeah so set the visibility when its shown. You are asking for something that isnt supported by button sheets, you are going to have to compromise somewhere

Comment: thank you I'll try another way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have solved this by using Dialog(full screen) with custom(bottom)  animations.

Design:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorTransparent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_close"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/fifty_dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/thirty_dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_close_filter"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">


<!-- All your required widgets here-->
    </LinearLayout> </LinearLayout>
```

Java Code:

```
  Dialog filterDialog;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_filter, null);

    final ImageView close = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.img_close);

    builder.setView(rootView);

    filterDialog = builder.create();

    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp2 = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    Window window = filterDialog.getWindow();
    filterDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    lp2.copyFrom(window.getAttributes());
    //This makes the dialog take up the full width
    lp2.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    lp2.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    window.setAttributes(lp2);
    Window dialogWindow = filterDialog.getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialogWindow.getAttributes();
    dialogWindow.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM );

    filterDialog.getWindow().setWindowAnimations(R.style.CustomDialogAnimation);
    filterDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as -

```
<!--you bottom sheet linear layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!--Layout contains button-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:clickable="false"   
            >

            <!--Your button-->
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:src="your drawable"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:clickable="true"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!--put Your other views in below linear layout -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Note : clickable false is very important point. Doing this you can access view behind your linear layout. Also set background color to transparent

Comment: did not work for me I'm already doing the same thing but close icon is showing in the dialog with white background. not effect on making its parent  and child background transparet